# How to efficiently implement Maxpooling in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I have implemented CNN in Matlab, but my implementation takes too much time. I have identified which part is more time consuming. It is max-pooling related code below:

```
%blockwise operation
fun = @(block_struct) max_matrix(block_struct.data);
%downsampling
maxpool = cell(number_feature_map,1);
for i=1:number_feature_map
     maxpool{i}=blockproc(y{i},[2 2],fun);
end
function [maximum]=max_matrix(A)
maximum=max(A(:));
```

Without this (downsampling) it takes only 2 minutes to converge.
How can I make it efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `blockproc` you can use `kron` to create indices of blocks and use `accumarray` to apply `max` to each block. assumed number of rows and column are even and assumed `data` are random matrices of size `[6,8]`

```
r = 6 ,c=8

idx = kron(reshape(1:(r*c/4),c/2,[]).',ones(2))

for ii=1:number_feature_map
    data = rand(r,c);
    maxpool{ii} = reshape(accumarray(idx(:),data(:),[],@max),c/2,[]).';
end
```